# Как записать в дочернюю таблицу все строки родительской, где находится определенный параметр?mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Имеется родителькая таблица "студенты" Поле№1=ФИО Поле№2=Номер группы
так же имеется таблица ведомости  в которой есть поле ФИО

ВОПРОС

Как записать во вторую таблицу(ведомость) все ФИО студентов группы 333

как в коде mysql это выглядит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так (имена таблиц заменить нужными Вам):

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT fio
FROM table1
WHERE group = 333;
```

И, по-хорошему, Вам не помешало бы прочитать вот эту страницу: [MySQL Insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)